# Python event scheduler to run only once after a certain time

Tags: python-3.x, scheduled-tasks

Suppose I want to run a function after e.g. 10 seconds when it is called, and only run it once, how could I achieve this without having to wait for the duration of the time as seen below. Is there a better means of schedulisation for only running a function ONCE, not continuously?

```
import time
def f():
    time.sleep(10)
    print('f')

f()
```

Comment: what is the problem with the current solution?

Comment: I have to 10 seconds when its in another function. I want to carry on running code and have this in the background

Comment: but u are calling `f` once

Comment: Sorry. I mean't that i want it to run in the background without having to wait. As in my actual project I am calling it from another function with more code underneath this function call

Comment: Use threads then. https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/